# Каждый элемент одного ключа массива соответствует каждому элементу других ключей массива

Tags: php, массивы

уже второй день голову ломаю как решить данную проблему. Поиск к сожалению ничего не дает (может ищу неправильно). Задача следующая:

Массив с данными:

```
[19811] => Array
    (
        [Цветовая температура (K)] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3000
                [1] => 4000
            )

        [Угол светораспределения] => Array
            (
                [0] => 15°
                [1] => 30°
                [2] => 50°
            )

        [Цвет корпуса] => Array
            (
                [0] => белый
                [1] => серый
                [2] => черный
            )

    )
```

Кол-во элементов во втором массиве и названия ключей произвольные, например в этом их 3 (температура, светораспределения, цвет). Могут быть любые название и любое кол-во элементов, например:

[19811] => Array
    (

```
    [Мощность] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 60
        )

    [Цвет корпуса] => Array
        (
            [0] => белый
            [1] => серый
            [2] => черный
        )

)
```

Получается что может быть как 1 ключ, так и несколько с разными названиями. Кол-во элементов в каждом ключе тоже произвольное.

Задача в следующем, нужно чтобы каждому элементу соответствовали все элементы следующих ключей т.е. берем кол-во вариаций температура (2)* угол(3) * цвет(3), получается 18 вариаций вида:

```
[Цветовая температура (K)] => 3000
[Угол светораспределения] => 15
[Цвет корпуса] => белый
```

Следующий:

```
[Цветовая температура (K)] => 3000
[Угол светораспределения] => 15
[Цвет корпуса] => Серый
```

и тд, последний:

```
[Цветовая температура (K)] => 4000
[Угол светораспределения] =>  50°
[Цвет корпуса] => Черный
```

Каким образом это можно сделать на PHP. Заранее спасибо если сможете помочь. Важна реализация именно на PHP

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря [splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58) (гигансткий плюс ему к карме) был найден правильный ответ, вот код функции которая возвращает нужный массив.

```
function cartesian(array $input)
{
    $result = [[]];
    foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
        $append = [];
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            foreach ($result as $data) {
                $append[] = $data + [$key => $value];
            }
        }
        $result = $append;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Подробное обсуждение видно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays), там же есть и другие варианты

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
  '19811'=> array(
    'Цветовая температура (K)' => array(
      '0' => '3000',
      '1' => '4000'
    ),

    'Угол светораспределения' => array(
      '0' => '15°',
      '1' => '30°',
      '2' => '50°'
    ),

    'Цвет корпуса' => array(
      '0' => 'белый',
      '1' => 'серый',
      '2' => 'черный'
    )
  )
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  # code...
  for ($i = 0; $i <3 ; $i++) {
    # code...
    foreach ($value['Цвет корпуса'] as $key0 => $value1) {
      # code...
      $data[] = array(
        'id' => $key,
        'НАЗВАНИЕ' => 'TOP LED Lens 13W',
        'Тип источника света' => 'Светодиод (LED)',
        'Мощность (Вт)' => '13',
        'Световой поток (lm)' => '1470',
        'Цена' => '0',
        'Цветовая температура (K)' => $value['Цветовая температура (K)'][$i],
        'Угол светораспределения' =>  $value['Угол светораспределения'][$i],
        'Цвет корпуса' => $value1
      );
    }
  }
}

print_r($data);
```

примерно так

Comment: К сожалению таким образом соответствие не работает. Нужно чтобы для каждого элемента было соответствие всем остальным элементам т.е. для температуры 3000 должны быть все варианты углов (3 штуки) и цветов (3 штуки)

Comment: А тут еще получается, что при $i = 2, температура будет пустая

Comment: у меня пустая )

Comment: К сожалению это работает если ключа 2 и у них одинаковое кол-во элементов. К сожалению у меня ключей может быть от 1 до N и кол-во элементов в них произвольное от 2ух до N

Comment: поменял........

Comment: добовляй count учись сам работать с массивами.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, c count'ом умею работать. Не понимаю как тут он пройдет все ключи и все значения. В данном случае получается 18 вариаций, значит $i < 18 и этот код просто не сработает

Comment: 18 вариаций чего?

Comment: 2 температуры, 3 угла, 3 цвета.Каждому элементу соответствуют все остальные элементы. Получается 2*3*3 = 18

Comment: посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays/15973172#15973172

Comment: Это потрясающе!!! Сто тысяч благодарностей, работает для всех вариантов!!!!!!!!!!! Спасибо!!!!!!!

Comment: ставь + .......

Comment: с радостью бы, но нигде не вижу его. Видимо у меня еще такого нету